# Kafka Streams: Clearing objects after forward to topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Let's assume the value is a String OR a class object.

```
context.forward(key, value, topic);
```

Immediately after the above line, can we do the following?  If the records are in producer buffer, will they all get published to topic as null?

```
value = null;
```

Comment: i believe you are modifying reference of that object in your code but not in buffer, you should try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine, as you pass on references. If `value` would be primitive type (not possible of this API), the value would be copied what would also be fine.

What might result in problems is, if you *modify* the passed object (not possible to do with `String` type though). Assume, it's a POJO type, and you call a `set()` after `context.forward` -- because the downstream node might still use the passed in reference, calling `set()` would modify the previous forwarded POJO. This could cause problems.